# Classify LAS points based on shapefile

Tags: lidr

I am using R and the current 3x version of the lidR package to process point clouds.  Sections of my point cloud are 'unclassified' and I need them to be classified as 'ground'.  (These mis-classifications are happening at interstate overpasses.)  I would like to manually assign these points their 'ground' classification value.  If I were using a GIS, I would select the points using my road polygon and manually reassign their classification value.  Is there a workflow in v3x of the lidR package to do this - to change a point's classification based on, in my case, a polygon shapefile?

In v1.6, there was a command called *lasclassify* that would allow me to create a user defined attribute in the point cloud and assign my own classifications (as in the lasclassify example shown here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lidR/versions/1.6.1/topics/lasclassify).  I think it has been long deprecated, though.

There is not much to see, but I provide my code below for anybody who is interested:

```
library(lidR)
library(rgdal)
mypath<- "c:/myPath/"    
tdat<- readLAS(file.path(myPath,"myLas.las"))

shppath<- myPath
shpname<- "myRoadPolygon"
shape_spdf<- readOGR(dsn = shppath, layer = shpname)
shppoly<- shape_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]

###here I would like to select the points in *tdat* by the polygon shapes in *shppoly*...
```

Answer (score 2):

The function that replaces `lasclassify()` from v1.x is `merge_spatial()`. Below an example were I'm using a polygon of lake to classify as water

```r
library(lidR)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
shpfile <- system.file("extdata", "lake_polygons_UTM17.shp", package = "lidR")

las <- readLAS(LASfile)
shp <- shapefile(shpfile)

las <- merge_spatial(las, shp, attribute = "in_poly")
las$Classification[las$in_poly] <- LASWATER
las$in_poly <- NULL
plot(las, color = "Classification")
```